# Cannot resolve method using(com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebaseui, android-glide

I'm trying to use the awesome Glide integration provided by FirebaseUI, but I am unable to do so.

I have followed everything described here: [Downloading images with FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui)

***Cannot resolve method using(com.ui.firebase.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader)***

is the error that I am currently getting.

#### Are my settings good?

Here are the versions of the two libraries I am using:

- Glide 4.0.0-RC1
- FirebaseUI 2.0.1

And this is my gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, FirebaseUI doesn't yet support Glide 4.0 so you have two options:

1. Downgrade Glide to `v3.8.0`
2. Write your own Glide Module. You can see my response [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/783#issuecomment-312949267) on how you would go about upgrading the FirebaseUI storage code.

This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/731

Edit: As per link above, the issue has been resolved in version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

You must include `firebase-ui-storage` in your Gradle dependencies (/app/build.gradle) as follows:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.1'
}
```

Check: [last version of this library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

And then import the package:

```
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
```

Answer (score 1):

That happend to me and I solved it with:

```
// FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'
// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
```

Here is the MyAppGlideModule that needs to extend AppGlideModule.
It is of vital importance to Override the "registerComponents" function:

```
@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
  @Override
  public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry 
  registry) {
    // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
    registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
            new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
}
```

}

And the function that actually downloads the image:

```
import com.app.path.where.the.myappglidemodule.is.GlideApp;
"Ex: import com.firebase.uidemo.storage.GlideApp  //In case MyAppGlideModule is inside storage package"

public void downloadDirect(StorageReference imageRef, ImageView imageView) {
    try {
        if (imageRef != null) {
            // Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
            // (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
            GlideApp.with(this)
                    .load(imageRef)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .into(imageView);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Null image storage reference!");
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
}
```